# New version of Drools-Guvnor

Tags: jboss, wildfly, drools-guvnor, wildfly-8

I am currently using Drools-Guvnor 5.5 on JBoss 7 for Business rule management system.
I am planing to update both of them. So jBoss goes to WildFly - 8.

Now what about Drools-Guvnor? From what I understood it is now called Workbench. Am I correct or are they different.
I did download Workbench war file for WildFly 8  but after seeing it I don't think it is what I want.
Any help is appriciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I read in the JBoss forums that Guvnor is now the KIE (Drools) Workbench. I am not sure I completely understand this but it seems that Guvnor no longer exists and has been replaced by this workbench thing.

If you look on [Drools.org](http://www.drools.org/)  there is a symbol for the Guvnor software (the acropolis type of government building with all of the columns). This symbol is next to the words, "Drools Workbench (web UI for authoring and management)", which I think means that Drools now contains this software that I think was a separate program in the past.